# I'd like to make "Any Part of Field" Default (Access VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

In a simple Find action dialog box on an MSAccess (2007) form I want to make "Any Part of Field" the default value when the Find and Replace box appears.

The actual default value is "whole field". I though that I could change that with the following line:

```
DoCmd.FindRecord " ", acAnywhere, , , , , False
```

But that doesn't make any difference. The rest of the code works fine (associated with a command button). But that above line does nothing whether it's there or not. Please help. I have the following code:

```
Private Sub AppNAppFind_Click()
On Error GoTo AppNAppFind_Click_Err

On Error Resume Next
Err.Clear

DoCmd.FindRecord " ", acAnywhere, , , , , False
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFind


If (MacroError <> 0) Then
    Beep
    MsgBox MacroError.Description, vbOKOnly, ""
End If


AppNAppFind_Click_Exit:
   Exit Sub

AppNAppFind_Click_Err:
   MsgBox Error$
   Resume AppNAppFind_Click_Exit
```

I'm using Access 2007.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me in Access 2010.

```
Private Sub myFind_Click()
DoCmd.GoToControl "=[Screen].[PreviousControl].[Name]"
DoCmd.FindRecord " ", acAnywhere, False, acSearchAll, False, acCurrent, False
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdFind
End Sub
```

I verified that the Access default for "Find" is "Whole Field" on this machine, yet when I click my button the Find dialog has "Any Part of Field" selected for "Match".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is an option in Access 2007, but in Access 2016, you can go to `File > Options > Client Settings` and look for `Default find/replace behaviour` and change it from `Fast search` to `General search` and it will set the default find settings to Look in: `Current document` and match in `Any Part of Field`.

This setting is for the client and will be effective in any access db you open and is persistent.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub MyButton_Click()
  Me.MyControl.SetFocus

  Dim WshShell As Object
  Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  
  WshShell.SendKeys "^f", True
  WshShell.SendKeys "%l{UP}", True
  WshShell.SendKeys "%ha", True
  WshShell.SendKeys "%n", True

End Sub
```

Comment: The VBA code above is simple and works well. Create a button and add the code to it so you can go to the field, open the Find/Replace dialog box and set it to search current field and any part of field.